# 2008 Jeep Liberty rear lower control arm bolt

Tags: jeep, liberty, control-arm

I'm trying to find a bolt for a rear lower control arm on a 2008 Jeep Liberty.  The closest I have been able to find is https://parts.thomascdj.com/v-2008-jeep-liberty--sport--3-7l-v6-gas/rear-suspension--rear-suspension-and-cradle

[image: Rear Suspension]

#11 is a bolt with I'm guessing a retainer clip on the side.  The site lists out all the part numbers...except #11.  My clip broke when I tried to remove the bolt.  I haven't been able to get a good grip on the clip side and I'm planning on cutting it if I can't remove it.

My question is, do I just use #7 on both sides?  Can I just go get any Grade 8 bolt that fits for this?  The arm is snapped and I have not bought a replacement yet, but I don't see any indication the bolts come with the control arm.

Comment: Take a look, but I'd lay wager #8 and #11 are the same. You should be able to measure them on the vehicle (length wise) to see if they are the same length (219 mm). You can look at them to see if they are the same size (M12) ... check the head of the bolt to see what the wrench (spanner) size is for it. If they match, they should be the same thickness in the shank.

Comment: I was able to find the original part number.  It has been discontinued and replaced by the bolt used on the other end, #7.  I finally had nice weather to get out there, had to cut #11, but #7 came off cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

I found the original part number as 6508678AA, which has been replaced by part 6507620AA, or #7 in this picture.